# AngularJS - jQuery Droppable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I am running into an issue implementing a simple jQuery droppable in an AngularJS app.

For some reason, the code is working on a standalone page I set up on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65FMq/3/

However, for some reason when I add the same code in myApp it does not work.  Basically as soon as you launch the app (index.html) you'd be in the home page which includes the app.js, the other controllers, css, etc all there.

Then, once you click on the menu item Photos, I would then show the "photos" state (which is a separate html file).  From there, the user can then select one of the photos he/she would like to purchase, and when he clicks the buy button, using ng-click"buyPhoto(photos)", I hide the div showing the photos available and show the div with more details on that photo.

There, apart from information on the photo, I am also showing a grid with all the possible sizes that the user can order the photo in, and he would need to drag and drop the size he'd like to the order bar (droppable area).  However, for some reason I am not getting the drag/drop effect even though the required jquery css/js files are loaded and the photo thumbnail (which would be the cell in the fiddle above) is being set to draggable.

Here's my app.js:

```
angular
.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
        })
        .state('photos', {
            url: '/photos',
            templateUrl: 'partials/photos.html',
            controller:  'photosCtrl',
            resolve: { photos: ['$http', function($http){
                        return $http.get('api/photos.json').then(function(response){
                            return response.data;
                        });
                    }]
            }                       
        })  

}]);
```

Here's my photosCtrl:

```
angular.module('app')
 .controller('photosCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'photos', function($scope, $http, photos) {

$scope.photos       = photos;

$scope.buyPhoto = function(photos) {                    
    document.getElementById('photos_available').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('photo_buy').style.display = 'block';   

    $scope.photo_name   = photos.photo_name;
    $scope.image        = photos.image;
    $scope.description  = photos.description;
    $scope.date_taken   = photos.date_taken;
    $scope.price        = photos.price; 
    $scope.rows         = 3;
    $scope.cells        = 3;
    $scope.getNumber = function (num) {
           return new Array(num);
    }       


}])
.filter('character',function(){
return function(input){
    return String.fromCharCode(64 + parseInt(input,10));
};
});


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#cell-container ul.rows li.draggable").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$("#droppable ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
});
});
```

HTML (snippet) in the Photos partial html file (which contains where the angular repeating is happening to generate the required cells and rows, and to show that the rows are given the class draggable):

```
    <div class="cell-selection-container" id="cell-container">
        <ul class="rows">
            <li class="row" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(rows) track by $index">
                <ul class="cells">
                    <li class="cell draggable" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(cells) track by $index" id="{{$index+1}}" id="{{$parent.$index+1|character}}{{$index+1}}">
                        <div class="cell-number">{{$parent.$index+1|character}}{{$index+1}}</div>
                    </li>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="droppable">
    <ol>
        <li class="placeholder">drop stuff here</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```